To find partial derivative of a function involving tetration and nested arctan

Hopefully I am allowed to post picture of the question itself if it visible enough .
My attempt :-
Given $f(x,y)=x^{x^{x^{x^y}}}+\ln(x)[\tan^-(\tan^-(\tan^-(\sin(\cos xy)-\ln(x+y))))]  $
I assumed $u(x,y)=x^{x^{x^{x^y}}}$ .
Then $u(1,2)=1$ and
$u_x(1,2)=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {(1+h)^{g(h)} -1}h $
Where $g(h)={(1+h)^{(1+h)^{(1+h)^2}}}$
We note $g(h)\rightarrow 1$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ , so Applying L-Hospitals Rule , to above limit , we get .
$u_x (1,2)=\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac d{dh} \{ (1+h)^{g(h)} \}    $
Further calculation gives $u_x(1,2)=1$
Now we assume $v(x,y)= \ln(x)[\tan^-(\tan^-(\tan^-(\sin(\cos(xy)-\ln(x+y))))]  $
So $v(1 ,2)=0$ and $v_x(1,2)=\lim _{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ \ln (1+h)\psi (1+h,2)}h  $
Where $\psi(x,y)= \tan^-(\tan^-(\tan^-(\sin(\cos(xy)-\ln(x+y))))$
So , we get $v_x(1,2)=\psi(1,2)$
Now it's easy to show
$\sin(\cos 2) -\ln3 <0 $
So $v_x(1,2)<0$
Thus $f_x(1 ,2)< 1$ and similar reasoning for $(1,5)$ show $f_x (1, 5)<1$ and hence option (b) must be correct .
But checking by calculator doesn't seem to agree with (b) . Am I doing something wrong ?
